# @-moz-document url-prefix() is not recognized

Tags: css, firefox, mozilla, prefix

I am using Adobe Brackets as my editor and when something is not recognized it comes out in red. When I use @-moz-document url-prefix() to try and style for Firefox it comes out in red like so the image below and nothing changes in the Firefox browser. No matter which DIV i put in there it is always just the color red.

[image]

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please post code in text, not in image

Comment: For me, the code is not the issue, I am wondering if anyone has encountered this before. It doesn't matter what div I insert into their it just comes out red, which means it is not recognized. I've been looking for this everywhere but haven't been able to find the issue. I have the brackets in place correctly, but does not feed.

Comment: Works as expected : http://jsfiddle.net/u69emoL4/1/ Blue on Chrome, Purple on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

See there, a simple working example : http://jsfiddle.net/u69emoL4/1/

So I guess your problem is the following : you declare Firefox specific rules before the global rules.

Example :

```
#test {
    color: blue;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix()
{

  #test { color: purple;  }
}
```

Will be purple on Firefox, but :

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
{

  #test { color: purple;  }
}
#test {
   color: blue;
}
```

Will return blue. Because those two rules have same specificity, the last one will "won".